# Random white space below divs in container?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to find where the white space below my blocks container is coming from. I can fix it by adding a negative `margin-bottom`, but I'm wondering where it is coming from in the first place. I want it to be on the very bottom border on the container div.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sv7eqoff/

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Positioning</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="positioning.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav></nav>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="topbar"></div>
        <div id="blocks">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0px 0px;
}
nav {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
}

#container {
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 40px auto;
}

#topbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: lightgray;
}

#blocks div {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

footer {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/image-inside-div-has-extra-space-below-the-image you will get more explanation here also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because those DIVs are `inline-block;` elements, which are aligned at the baseline (like text), meaning that some whitespace below that baseline is reserved for those parts of the letters which go under the line (like in letters g, j, p etc.).

You can avoid that by using `vertical-align: top` on `inline-block` elements.

Comment: That did the trick! thank you

Comment: with your reputation i guess it's better to close as duplicate :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Actually I'm faster writing the answer (and therefore also answering a particular question, not suppling some generic answer) than searching and finding a duplicate...